# ListView element change by clicking another element of same row

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, baseadapter, getview

I have a ListView and a simple adapter class with two element. I just want to change one element by clciking the other one but whenever I scroll down or up the change is disappear. I have studied this two links

[Why do items disappear when I scroll the listView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6118419/why-do-items-disappear-when-i-scroll-the-listview)

[Clickable element in custom ListView row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27817429/clickable-element-in-custom-listview-row)

I know that listView has recycling feature which is the reason for this but I want a simple solution without refresh the whole list and when I will change on multiple rows, it should be there after getView called I mean after scroll up or down. 
here is my adapter class code

```
public class Pha extends BaseAdapter {

private List<PhaMessages> pList = new ArrayList<PhaMessages>();
private Activity context;
ViewHolder viewHolder = null;

int fCounted = 0;


public Pha(Activity cont, ArrayList<PhaMessages> posts){
    this.context = cont;
    this.pList = posts;
    Log.d("pha","called constructor..");
}

static class ViewHolder {
    protected TextView fCount;
    protected ImageView fIcon;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return pList.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


    if (convertView == null) {

        LayoutInflater inflator = context.getLayoutInflater();
        convertView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.pha_list_row, null);
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();


        viewHolder.fIcon = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.f_counter_img);
        viewHolder.fCount = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.f_plus);


        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);

    } else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

    }

    final ViewHolder hold = viewHolder;

        viewHolder.fCount.setText("" + pList.get(position).NumFrnd);



    viewHolder.fIcon.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


                if(!t){
                    fCounted++;


                    hold.fCount.setText(""+fCounted);

        // by doing this at list I can see an immediate change that the number is changing
        //
        //but is i do viewHolder.fCount.setText(""+fCounted); I see another row changing

                }else {
                    Toast.makeText(context,"You have already clcik this.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }


        }
    });

    return convertView;
}

}
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: The value you change in hold.fCount.setText, update that value in your arrayList `posts` as well. So that next time view will be reloading, you will get updated value only.

Comment: thanks, can you please explain where should i do that change? I mean if i click on multiple rows then everytime i have to change on the value on "posts" and also call the constructor to get the change?

Comment: You need to set this value in `pList`, not in `posts`. and you will call this right below `hold.fCount.setText` in `onClickListener`

Answer (score 0):

When you increment`fCounted` value increment that value in your collection ie `pList`as well

in your `getview` method  put position as tag in `fCount` component

```
viewHolder.fIcon.setTag(position);  // this is to get exact position for which we will change/increment value
```

Now in fIcon's OnClickListener method

```
   viewHolder.fIcon.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


                if(!t){
                    fCounted++;

                  hold.fCount.setText(""+fCounted);
                  int position = (int)v.getTag();
                  int oldValue = pList.get(position).NumFrnd;
                  pList.get(position).NumFrnd = ++oldValue;
          }

}
};
```

Comment: cannot resolve method setTag(int) when I put fCount.setTag(position); where should I put this?

Comment: `viewHolder.fIcon.setTag(position);` add this line before    `viewHolder.fCount.setText("" + pList.get(position).NumFrnd);`

Comment: thanks, I have already done that but getting exception at `int position = (int)v.getTag();` Actually I got the solution by removing set and get tags just a simple insertion on pList as @Darpan said.